# Relationship between 3 Models in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, php-7, laravel-5.6

I have 3 models :

```
Dog
id - name - puce - birhtday
Category
id - name
Event
id - date - name - dog_id - category_id
```

I would like to get on the individual page of each dog a separate table for each category with the list of all the events of this category.

Comment: Please clarify your question and show us what you tried

Comment: I have a list of dogs - and a list of events and a list of categories - I would like to get a list based on the dog selected events by categories

Comment: database events => id | date_event | description_event | dog_id | category_id |